# What kind of syntax is this when a whole class is passed to the background value

Tags: reactjs

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const imagesLoadedOptions = { background: '.my-bg-image-el' }

    return (
        <Masonry
            className={'my-gallery-class'}
            elementType={'ul'}
            options={masonryOptions}
            imagesLoadedOptions={imagesLoadedOptions}
        >
            <div className="my-bg-image-el"></div>
        </Masonry>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Super unclear what is this? What is background value? And where it is used or passed? Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That's just an object with the field name `background` and value `'.my-bg-image-el'`, a string.

Comment: It seems like you have to share the Masonry component implementation... at a first sight it seems just an object prop that the Masonry component uses inside of it... there is no class concept here... is just a React prop passed to a component.